# Filter_time Function - To filter Time in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do some time series forecasting based on this blog from R Bloggers.
[Time Series Forecasting using keras](https://www.r-bloggers.com/deep-learning-for-time-series-forecasting-predicting-sunspot-frequency-with-keras/)

This is my code that i am trying use.

```
# Core Tidyverse
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

# Time Series
library(timetk)
library(tidyquant)
library(tibbletime)
library(stats)

# Visualization
library(cowplot)

# Preprocessing
library(recipes)

# Sampling / Accuracy
library(rsample)
library(yardstick) 

# Modeling
library(keras)
library(tfruns)

#reading excel file

library("readxl")
incoming_volume <- read_excel(file.choose())

volume <- incoming_volume %>%
  tk_tbl() %>%
  mutate(index = as_date(index)) %>%
  as_time(index = index)

p1 <- volume %>%
  ggplot(aes(index, value)) +
  geom_point(color = palette_light()[[1]], alpha = 0.5) +
  theme_tq() +
  labs(
    title = "From July 2011 to May 2018 "
  )

p2 <- volume %>%
  filter_time("start" ~ "2011") %>%
  ggplot(aes(index, value)) +
  geom_line(color = palette_light()[[1]], alpha = 0.5) +su
  geom_point(color = palette_light()[[1]]) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.2, se = FALSE) +
  theme_tq() +
  labs(
    title = "2011 to 2018 (Zoomed In To Show Changes over the Year)",
    caption = "Incoming Volume"
  )
```

I get an error stating that filter_time function could not be found. 
I tried time_filter as well. I am getting the same error.

How could i avoid this error.

Regards,
Ren.

Answer (score 0):

You can change "filter_time" by :

```
require(lubridate)

p2 <- volume %>%
      filter(year(as.Date(index)) > 2011)
```

Comment: `plot_grid(p_title, p1, p2, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(0.1, 1, 1))`. This is the error message i get.  `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'value' not found`. Where p_title is `p_title <- ggdraw() + 
  draw_label("Incoming Volume", size = 18, fontface = "bold", colour = palette_light()[[1]])`